# Why does Google Cloud Endpoints reverse the order of my parameters?

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

I have the following endpoint method:

```
public class PlayerEndpoint {
  private static final String PLAYER_NAME = "player_name";
  private static final String PLAYER_UUID = "player_uuid";

  @ApiMethod(name = "register", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST, path="register")
  public Player register(@Named(PLAYER_UUID) String uuid,
                         @Named(PLAYER_NAME) String playerName) {
  log.info(String.format("Registering user uuid: %s name: %s", uuid, playerName));
  ...
  }
}
```

When I call this from my Android client:

```
String uuid = "test_uuid";
String name = "test_name";
playerEndpoint.register(uuid, name).execute();
```

The backend logs:

```
Registering user uuid: test_name name: test_uuid
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Can't believe this issue exists with SDK 1.9.50 - the latest one right now. Its been an year...I wasted an hour on this.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  Apparently Endpoints sorts your methods alphabetically.

> **Method parameters in the generated client library are in alphabetical order**, regardless of the original order in the backend method. As a result, you should be careful when editing your methods, especially if there are several parameters of the same type. The compiler will not be able to catch parameter-ordering errors for you.

https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/google-cloud-endpoints-for-android/

Comment: This doesn't happen if you don't specify the path attribute of a method. Is it a bug?

Comment: Thank you for this! I have wasted a lot of time debugging because of this "feature"!